# VS code cannot connect to computer instances in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

The original question can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/469700/terminal-of-computer-instance-keeps-loading-and-at.html). I am posting the question here again, because it seems to be an issue of VS code instead of Azure Machine Learning according to the AML team.

I haven't experienced this issue indeed, if I only use Azure Machine Learning in the browser without trying to connect to VS code. If I try to connect with VS code, the same issue happens.

Could someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I alerted the product group PM about this. If you or your company has an Enterprise agreement with Azure/MSFT, I recommend you open a priority support ticket for faster resolution

Comment: Hi @AndersSwanson, thanks a lot for forwarding! It seems that my company does not have the kind of agreement including technical support, so I cannot open a ticket for this. I would hope that the tech team could solve this issue asap, since I also saw some other user also reporting that the relevant extension is/was quite buggy...

Comment: Sounds like you're having a bug, do you mind opening a [GitHub Issue][1] and linking back to this question?


  [1]: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're having a bug, do you mind opening a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai) and linking back to this question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just saw that the MS team has already opened an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/issues/1174) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/issues/1173)

Answer (score 1):

We could see the terminal in Azure Machine Learning and tried to connect to the VScode compute instance as shown below, please retry the same.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please read my original question linked in the description. I am not saying that it is not possible to connect. I meant, it happens quite often.

Comment: Will forward to the product team for this intermittent issue.